# React Native - Reuse same component instance instead of a rerendered one?

Tags: react-native

So I have a custom tab component based solely on `activeTab` state:

```
<View style={styles.contentDisplayArea}> 
{ this.state.activeTab == "Children" && <Children /> }
{ this.state.activeTab == "Adults" && <Adults /> }
</View>
```

The `<Children />` and `<Adults />` components are imported components which have nested forms. When `Adults` is active I get the `<Adults />` component, I fill out the adult name and age  with `TextInput` fields, then I click the `Children` tab and get the `<Children />` component. When I go back to the `Adults` tab, I expect the same fields I filled out to be there, but it seems like the component is back to its initial state instead, with the fields I filled out emtpy.

So, how can I reuse the same component (instance/reference/cached) I filled out already instead of getting a freshly rendered empty one?

Comment: You could use a Navigator for that.  If you push another screen and then pop it your initial screen is at the same state with all input fields filled out like before the push.

Comment: Not sure how to push and pop within that specific area, since there is common things like header and the custom tabbar above, which shouldn't be repeated in both imported components.. In all my scenes, I am using a common layout, and the `contentDisplayArea` is where it should load either of those subcomponents.

Comment: Can you describe more what should stay the same.  If it's just a header and a tabbar you could implement them in the toolbar of the Navigator component.

Comment: I haven't used Navigator before and don't fully understand it or how to accomplish this with it. I've been using react-native-router-flux for routing but they're tabs integration has issues, and I can't get the above running correctly with it (you can't navigate to a nested tab) which the above are considered.. Based on some research, it seems Experimental Navigator will be the way forward instead of Navigator, so it all seems very unstable and that's why I wanted to keep using the current routing package I have, but use a custom tab component just for this form. Very confused atm..